# How to Create List of String in a Model : Extjs

Tags: extjs

How do i make a field as List of String elements while creating a Ext.data.Model in Ext js?

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age',   type: 'int', convert: null},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'alive', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the type:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'foo'}
    ]
});

var o = new User({
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
});
console.log(o.get('foo'));
```